# Generating Dropdown menu for Plotly charts

Tags: r, plotly

This is my code for stock volatility for 10 stocks:

```
   ##------------producing stock volatility plot---------##

p1 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.BPCL)) + geom_line(color = "blue") + 
     theme_bw()
p2 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.TCS)) + geom_line(color = "green") +
     theme_bw()
p3 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.CIPLA)) + geom_line(color = "red") +
     theme_bw()
p4 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.EICHER)) + geom_line(color = "pink") +
     theme_bw()
p5 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.INFY)) + geom_line(color = "yellow") +
     theme_bw()
p6 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.LT)) + geom_line(color = "purple") +
     theme_bw()
p7 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.MARUTI)) + geom_line(color = "orange") +
     theme_bw()
p8 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.RELIANCE)) + geom_line(color = "#7fffd4") +
     theme_bw()
p9 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.SUNPHARMA)) + geom_line(color = "#ff1493") +
     theme_bw()
p10 = ggplot(Closed_Price_Return, aes(Date, R.YESBANK)) + geom_line(color = "#ff7256")+ 
     theme_bw()

##------------Converting the ggplots into plotly objects-------##
p1 = ggplotly(p1)
p2 = ggplotly(p2)
p3 = ggplotly(p3)
p4 = ggplotly(p4)
p5 = ggplotly(p5)
p6 = ggplotly(p6)
p7 = ggplotly(p7)
p8 = ggplotly(p8)
p9 = ggplotly(p9)
p10 = ggplotly(p10)
```

Now i want to generate a dropdown menu button for all these charts. Please
tell me how to proceed for button code in plotly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is (like the example on [plotly page](https://plot.ly/r/dropdowns/)), create the plotly with all your traces invisible, then add a dropdown that switches the visible trace:

```
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~gear) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~cyl, name = "cyl", visible = F, color=I("blue")) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~hp, name = "hp", visible = F, color=I("green")) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~gear, name = "gears", visible = F, color=I("red")) %>%
  layout(
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 0.7,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
               label = "cyl"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
               label = "hp"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
               label = "gear")))
    )
  )
```

In your case, just define a different `y` in the `add_trace`s. The `TRUE`/`FALSE` lists must be as long as you have traces in your Dropdown.

This also works pretty straightforward with a small shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

p1 <- plot_ly(mtcars, x=~cyl, y=~gear)
p2 <- plot_ly(mtcars, x=~hp, y=~am)

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(selectInput("selectPlot", "Choose desired plot", choices=paste0("p", 1:2)), plotlyOutput("plot")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){      
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    return(get(input$selectPlot)) # get("p1") from the workspace returns the object p1, which is a plotly object
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the help , i have used the first method ,it is lot more easy to use.

Comment: great answer! I really like this one!